# UIlabel dynamic width and restrain within in a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

I have a UIcollectionview cell will display a label and a small image on the right side of the label

The label can dynamically adjust the width and the image have to adjust the position based on the label width. And all of them must remain inside the cell.

I wish to know how to create this no matter programmatically or by storyboard, thanks

cell sample

[image: cell sample]

Comment: Can you show us how you want to set the label and image in cell, i mean the UI

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore I have included the screenshot

Comment: the text would be of 2 lines or more than that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

Use a view (yellow view) as container of label and your image (green circular dot)

[image]

[image]

---

**Constraints for each UIElements**

Image:

[image]

Container View (Yellow View)

[image]

Label:

[image]

Green Dot (Image)

[image]

Settings of UILabel

### [image]

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: container maybe a good way, but the green dot will move the position based on the length of the label?